# Unlock phone with dead screen locked through Android Device Manager

Tags: adb, lock-screens, broken-screen

My screen is dead and I want to unlock my phone so I can access it through Kies to backup my pictures.

I locked the phone through Android Device Manager setting an easy password (was hoping for an Unlock option once I locked it) and tried various methods to unlock it for example:

```
adb shell input text 1234
```

Since I don't know what the lock screen look like I'm not sure of the correct inputs to unlock it.

I know the phone is on and that it responds to adb. I am also able to run apps on it through Eclipse. It's a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0.

Comment: I've managed to get a view on the screen through Droid@Screen but the phone keeps saying wrong pin code even though I'm sure it's the same I set through Android Device Manager.